# How to pass default parameters to the @Query class in Nest.Js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to pass the default parameters `maxnodes=3` and `addstats=false` to the controller via the @Query parameter in Nest.Js.

The code works fine, but the default parameters are not used. When I pass on the query parameters the ones that are passed are shown, but if none are passed, the default values (`3` and `false`)  are not used.

How to fix that?

**context.contructor.ts:**

```
import { CreateContextQuery } from './context.query';
import { CreateContextDto } from './context.dto';

@Post('graph')
  public async createGraphForContext(
    @Body('context') contextData: CreateContextDto,
    @Query()
    contextQuery: CreateContextQuery,
  ) {
    const before = Date.now();

    const { context } = await this.contextService.createContext(contextData);

    const graph = await this.contextService.getGraphOfContext(
      context.id,
      contextQuery.maxnodes,
      contextQuery.addstats,
    );

}
```

**context.query.ts:**

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class CreateContextQuery {
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'Maximum number of nodes to show on the graph',
  })
  maxnodes;
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'Include graph statistics',
  })
  addstats;
  constructor(maxnodes = 3, addstats = false) {
    this.maxnodes = maxnodes;
    this.addstats = addstats;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So basically in your DTO, you can give default values.

```
export class CreateContextQuery {
  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsNumber()
  @Min(0)
  maxnodes?: number = 3;

  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => Boolean)
  @IsBoolean()
  addstats?: boolean = false;

  constructor(maxnodes = 3, addstats = false) {
    this.maxnodes = maxnodes;
    this.addstats = addstats;
  }
}
// as you can see i am using validation too
```

And in your controller :

```
  @Post('graph')
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })) 
// you need to add this for tansformation
  public async createGraphForContext(
    @Body('context') contextData: CreateContextDto,
    @Query()
    contextQuery: CreateContextQuery,
  ) {
    const before = Date.now();

    const { context } = await this.contextService.createContext(contextData);

    const graph = await this.contextService.getGraphOfContext(
      context.id,
      contextQuery.maxnodes,
      contextQuery.addstats,
    );

}
```

PS

Also if you want you can add custom decorators, in your case:
// add this decorator

```
export const GetContextQuery = createParamDecorator((_data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext): CreateContextDto => {
  const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  const query = request.query;

  const maxnodes = parseInt(query.maxnodes) || 3;//default values here in case it fails to parse
  const addstats = Boolean(query.addstats) || 0;
  return { addstats, addstats };
});
```

and in your controller, you can call the decorator  instead of `@Query`
just add your decorator `@GetContextQuery() context: CreateContextDto`, and now you do not need the UsePipes

Comment: I think the return should be `return {maxnodes, addstats};`

Answer (score 0):

What you receive in the query param is a plain object. You can achieve what you want putting a pipe in your query param and applying a class transform to instantiate the class.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#providing-defaults

`contextQuery` isn't an instance of `CreateContextQuery` because, without any configuration, Nest won't call `new CreateContextQuery` any time. This is why you end up using pipes (read this https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#transform-payload-objects)